# Binding a stencil render buffer to a frame buffer in opengl

Tags: opengl, framebuffer

Have anyone done this succesfully? It seems whatever index format I use in the stencil render buffer `glCheckFramebufferStatus(...)` returns `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_UNSUPPORTED`.
I've succesfully bound both a depth\color render buffer, but whenever I try to do the same thing with my stencil buffer I get (as I said) `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_UNSUPPORTED`.

Here is snippets of my code:

```
// Create frame buffer
GLuint fb;
glGenFramebuffers(1, &fb);

// Create stencil render buffer (note that I create depth buffer the exact same way, and It works.
GLuint sb;
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &sb);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, sb);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_STENCIL_INDEX8, w, h);

// Attach color
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, cb, 0);

// Attach stencil buffer
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fb);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, rb);
// And here I get an GL_FRAMEBUFFER_UNSUPPORTED when doing glCheckFramebufferStatus()
```

*Any ideas?*

Note: The color attachement is a texture and not a renderbuffer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Never use a free-standing stencil buffer. If you need stencil, always use a [depth+stencil image format](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Formats#Depth_stencil_formats). Note that the stencil index formats are not [required image formats](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Format#Required_formats).

Even though you're not using a depth buffer here, you still should use `GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8`, which you should attach to `GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT​`.

Comment: +1 Hmm I think I tried it but didn't work, however it works at my ATI card at home, if I get it to work at my nvidia at work, I'll give your answer green :)

Comment: @ViktorSehr: It may not be the stencil; what image format are you using for your texture?

Comment: @Viktor, did the stencil worked as free-standing buffer?

Nicol, if I need stencil and color, what could I choose?

Comment: @elect: My answer is quite clear about what you use: a combined depth/stencil image. You simply ignore the depth part of it.

Comment: @NicolBolas I have a question regarding this:If I specify depth renderbuffer along with the stencil then should I also specify the format GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8 to the depth buffer? and GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT​ too? Or the depth buffer is created as usual with GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT and GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24 ?

Comment: AS ALWAYS MR BOLAS WITH THE ANSWERS.  On iOS, even though the `GL_STENCIL_INDEX8` and `GL_STENCIL_INDEX8_OES` are defined, they do not seem to work at all (you always get `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_UNSUPPORTED`).  It seems you __must__ use the depth+stencil format `GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8_OES` to get the stencil buffer to work at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use stencil-only on recent nvidia hardware/drivers

```
glFramebufferTexture2DEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, GL_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_EXT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, fboStencilTexture, 0);
```

Still no support for both separate depth and stencil